# Multi Insert vs insert into Select

Tags: mysql

I have about 2000 rows to be inserted at a time. Which is Optimized method Multiinsert or insert into .. SEelec colum1, column2 from table .

In case if Multi-insert, I will SELECT generate multiple statments in my application.

So in short, which is Optimized?

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_list)
SELECT 
   select_list 
FROM 
   another_table
WHERE
   condition;
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO table(c1,c2,...)
VALUES 
   (v11,v12,...),
   (v21,v22,...),
    ...
   (vnn,vn2,...);
```

Answer (score 0):

For only 2,000 records, one INSERT will be most performant. Inserting batches of records is generally the best way to do it (with batch sizes up to as much as roughly 100,000 typically). It shouldn't matter if you use VALUE syntax or SELECT query syntax, as long as they're in the same batch.

This [article](https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723) does a good job going in depth on additional INSERT optimization techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Caution -- The `SELECT` could be the slow part.  Especially if you use `OFFSET`.

The `SELECT` is done in both cases, correct?

For the multi-row insert, the additional effort of sending the rows to the client, building the `INSERT`, and sending it back will *probably* make it the less desirable option.

Anyway, I would do the `INSERT..SELECT` for simplicity.

I like 1000 rows at a time.  You have a total of 2000, then do them all at once.  Less than that is slower (per row); more than that gets into "diminishing returns" *and* potential for hitting limits, clogging replication, etc, etc.

Thanks for the link -- Note that it and I agree on 1000 being "optimal".